# using a DLL in a .NET applications

Tags: c#, .net, dll, class-library

i want to add a class library to my project in C# 2008 and that class library is a wrapper for a C++ library.
i added the reference to the .NET wrapper and it says io.notfind exception.
i copied C++ DLLs to my project and again it says file not find exception.
what can i do to fix this?
the original C++ libraries where 2 DLLS that has lib files to but i did not copy those lib files because as i know they are for static linking

the library that i want to use is "awesomium" and the wrapper is awesomiumdotnet

Answer (score 2):

You could use [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check if there are any missing dependencies (which would normally result in a `FileNotFoundException`)

Answer (score 0):

1. You add a dependency manually or by using VS? Proper way is use of VS.
2. When error occurs? When you run application or when you compile it?